# How to plot three ggplot2 panels in one panel and one legend?

Tags: r, ggplot2

If I have this shapefile. I want to plot with three plots of it.

```
library(terra)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyterra)
v <- vect(system.file("ex/lux.shp", package = "terra"))
p1=ggplot(v) +
geom_spatvector(aes(fill = NAME_2), color = "grey") +
borders() +
coord_sf(xlim = c(4, 8), ylim = c(49, 49.5))
p2=ggplot(v) +
geom_spatvector(aes(fill = NAME_2), color = "grey") +
borders() +
coord_sf(xlim = c(4, 8), ylim = c(49.5, 50))
p3=ggplot(v) +
geom_spatvector(aes(fill = NAME_2), color = "grey") +
borders() +
coord_sf(xlim = c(4, 8), ylim = c(50, 50.5))
```

I can plot them all using this but I have three legends.

```
grid.arrange(p1,p2,p3)
```

How can I plot the three with only one legend but most importantly all figures have the same dimension (width and height).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to switch to the `patchwork` package to combine your plots which makes it easy to merge the legends using `plot_layout(guides = "collect")`.

```r
library(terra)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyterra)

v <- vect(system.file("ex/lux.shp", package = "terra"))
p1 <- p2 <- p3 <- ggplot(v) +
  geom_spatvector(aes(fill = NAME_2), color = "grey") +
  borders()

p1 <- p1 +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(4, 8), ylim = c(49, 49.5))
p2 <- p2 +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(4, 8), ylim = c(49.5, 50))
p3 <- p3 +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(4, 8), ylim = c(50, 50.5))

library(patchwork)

p3 + p2 + p1 +
  plot_layout(ncol = 1, guides = "collect")
```

[image]

Comment: I was going to suggest the brilliant ```patchwork``` package, too! In case it helps, you could also remove the repetitive x-axis labels for ```p2``` and ```p3``` by setting ```theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.title.x = element_blank())``` for them. Now your plot will share common x-axis labels. And you could shrink the space between the plots a touch by setting ```theme(plot.margin = margin(b=0))``` for each.

Comment: thanks, great, how can I remove the words lat and long from the plots?

Comment: Simply add ` & labs(x = NULL, y = NULL)` after `plot_layout(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing it is the `ggarrange` function from the `ggpubr` package.

```r
library(terra)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyterra)
library(ggpubr)

v <- vect(system.file("ex/lux.shp", package = "terra"))
p1=ggplot(v) +
  geom_spatvector(aes(fill = NAME_2), color = "grey") +
  borders() +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(4, 8), ylim = c(49, 49.5))
p2=ggplot(v) +
  geom_spatvector(aes(fill = NAME_2), color = "grey") +
  borders() +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(4, 8), ylim = c(49.5, 50))
p3=ggplot(v) +
  geom_spatvector(aes(fill = NAME_2), color = "grey") +
  borders() +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(4, 8), ylim = c(50, 50.5))

ggarrange(p3, p2, p1, common.legend = T, legend = "right", nrow = 3)
```

[image]